# How do you specify the framework version when creating an Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an Ionic tutorial that was developed under Ionic 3, and I'm having trouble creating my blank project with the right version of the framework, it defaults to Ionic 4.

How can I get it to create my project as Ionic 3 (e.g., Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.9.2)?

```
C:\workbench\>ionic start myProject blank
[..]
C:\workbench\>cd myProject 

C:\workbench\myProject> ionic info
[..]
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.0 (C:\Users\myhome\AppData\Roaming\npm\
                                           node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.3
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.3
@angular/cli                  : 7.2.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0
[..]
```

How do I get 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the actual version number to specify the frame work.

Instead you need to used the `--type=<type>` option.

`<type>` can be at least one of the following:

- `ionic1` - which will get you **ionic1 1.3.4**
- `ionic-angular` - which will get you **ionic-angular 3.9.2**
- `angular` - which will get you **ionic/angular 4.0.0**

There may be other's but I haven't encountered them yet.

In this particular case, the command would be: `ionic start myProject blank --type=ionic-angular`